# If $|g_x(y) -g_x(y’)|\leq w(d(y,y’))$, then $|\inf_x g_x(y) - \inf_x g_x(y’)|\leq w(d(y,y’))$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

In a book that I’m reading the author makes the following claim:

Let $w$ be a continuous positive monotone increasing function with $w(0)=0$, and $g_x$ be a family of functions indexed on $x$, such that:

$$|g_x(y) -g_x(y’)|\leq w(d(y,y’))
$$

Where $d$ is a metric.

Finally, the author claims that this implies that

$$|\inf_x g_x(y) - \inf_x g_x(y’)|\leq w(d(y,y’))$$

How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $y$ and $y'$ we can set $F(x) = g_x(y)$, $G(x) = g_x(y')$ and $K = w(d(y, y'))$, to simplify the notation and to get rid of the “red herrings” $w$ and $d$. Then the hypothesis is that
$$ \tag{1}
 \forall x: |F(x) - G(x)| \le K
$$
and the desired conclusion is
$$ \tag{2}
 |\inf_x F(x) - \inf_x G(x) | \le K \, .
$$

$(1)$ implies that
$$
 F(x) \ge G(x) - K \ge \inf_x G(x) - K
$$
for all $x$, and therefore
$$
\inf_x F(x) \ge \inf_x G(x) - K
$$
or
$$
 \inf_x G(x) - \inf_x F(x) \le K \, .
$$
In the same way one proves that
$$
 \inf_x F(x) - \inf_x G(x) \le K \, .
$$
and these inequalities together imply $(2)$.